# ruby each_line reads line break too?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read data from a text file and join it with a post string. When there's only one line in the file, it works fine. But with 2 lines, my request is failed. Is each_line reading the line break? How can I correct it?

```
File.open('sfzh.txt','r'){|f|
f.each_line{|row|
    send(row)
}
```

I did bypass this issue with split and extra delimiter. But it just looks ugly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, `each_line` includes line breaks. But you can strip them easily using [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000819):

```
File.foreach('test1.rb') do |line|
  send line.chomp
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mladen, it works. And thanks Greg, that's an extra lesson

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to map `strip` onto each line as it is returned. To read a file line-by-line, stripping whitespace and do something with each line you can do the following:

```
File.open("path to file").readlines.map(&:strip).each do |line|
   (do something with line)
end
```

Comment: be warned: `strip` is not the same as removing exactly the last line break, it also strips white spaces at the beginning of a line. So if you're like me, trying to read a tsv file(which could start with a bunch of tabs), `chomp` is the way to go as @mladen answered